# Relative item path in layout service call is not working

Tags: jss, layout-service

I am trying to access Sitecore 10.1 item via layout services and it is working fine with GUID and full path. But when I am trying to access it via a relative path from the current app, it is not working. like `https://cm.myproject.localhost/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?sc_site=MyProject&sc_apikey=06d43b65-6732-46b2-becd-ce047675df71&item=/CustomHome&sc_lang=en`.

However, it is working fine with this full item path like `https://cm.myproject.localhost/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?sc_site=MyProject&sc_apikey=06d43b65-6732-46b2-becd-ce047675df71&item=/sitecore/content/MyProject/CustomHome&sc_lang=en`

Comment: Is it a home page, it should be accessible by ‘/‘ only

Comment: No. It is not home page. Yes home page can be accessed with simple / but i want to access other pages.

Comment: you says that you can't access the following item: `/CustomHome`. But based on the full path `item=/sitecore/content/MyProject/CustomHome`, it look like this item is a site start item which will be accessible by `/` only. If I am wrong with my assumption, just add more details which item is a start item (let's say home) for your site, and whose other items you can't access

Comment: No. the Start item is a home item and it is being accessed correctly with /. /CustomHome item is a different item than home and I want to access it with a layout service call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have discussed the issue in a private chat and figured out, that the `/CustomHome` item are placed on the same level with a site start item which makes it impossible to resolved by relative path. In general, Layout Service item resolving process looks similar with an original item resolving: 1) Sitecore sites are resolved based on hostname or sc_site query string; 2) start item path (which is usually home page) is calculated based on the site configuration: `siteRoot` + `startItem` 3) the requested item is resolved based on the start item path + value from the `item` query string. If requested item is not under the site start item, it will be impossible to get it by relative path.